# Submit button needs to be clicked twice to call onSuccess Adaptor function in IBM Mobile First

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using AngularJS in a IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation app. I have a login form and when I click the **Login** button it collects some data and passes it to adapter invoke function. If it is successful it never calls success `loginSuccess` function. I need to click **Login** button twice so that the success function is called.

Why do I need to click button twice?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'view/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    });
});
```

**login.js**

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {

    $scope.login = function(usrName, pass) {

        var usrName = angular.element('#usrName').val();

        var pass = angular.element('#pass').val();
        console.log("Variable values: " + usrName + " : " + pass);
        $scope.loginProcedure = {
            adapter: 'SQL',
            procedure: 'login',
            parameters: [usrName, pass]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure, {
            onSuccess: $scope.loginSuccess,
            onFailure: $scope.loginFailure
        });

        $scope.loginSuccess = function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.resultSet = data.resultSet;
            console.log('success: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data + " : " + $scope.resultSet));
        };

        $scope.loginFailure = function() {
            console.log('failed');
        };
    }
});
```

**SQL-impl.js**

```
/*
 *  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 *  5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
 *  US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
 *  disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
 */
/************************************************************************
 * Implementation code for procedure - 'procedure1'
 *
 *
 * @return - invocationResult
 */
var loginStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select usrname,password from jay1 where usrname = ? and password=? ");

function login(usr, pass) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement: loginStatement,
        parameters: [usr, pass]
    });
}

/************************************************************************
 * Implementation code for procedure - 'procedure2'
 *
 *
 * @return - invocationResult
 */

function procedure2(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure: "storedProcedure2",
        parameters: [param]
    });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AB</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!--
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
                -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />

    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <!--application UI goes here-->

    <div id="view" ui-view></div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="library/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="library/angular.1.4.9.js"></script>
    <script src="library/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="library/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller/login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loginController" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 center-block" id="lgBlock">

    <!-- Login Box Start -->

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-group" name="lgForm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrName" required />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" required />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Box End -->

    <!--  error Modal start -->

    <div class="modal" role="modal" id="errorPopup">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Error</div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  error Modal End -->

</div>
```

Which is correct way to parse JSON data using angularJS `$scope`?

1) `$scope.data = data; $scope.resultSet = data.resultSet;`

2) `$scope.data = data; $scope.resultSet = $scope.data.resultSet;`

Answer (score 2):

You should take advantage of AngularJS two-way binding an update your login controller as follows:

**login.js**

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {

    $scope.login = function() {

        // TODO: if block to validate user input i.e., username and password

        $scope.loginProcedure = {
            adapter: 'SQL',
            procedure: 'login',
            parameters: [$scope.username, $scope.password]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure, {
            onSuccess: $scope.loginSuccess,
            onFailure: $scope.loginFailure
        });

        console.log($scope.loginProcedure);

        $scope.loginSuccess = function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            // resultSet is part of data so you don't need to refrences
            // you can use $scope.data.resultSet to access resultSet
            console.log('success: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data + " : " + $scope.data.resultSet));
        };

        $scope.loginFailure = function() {
            console.log('failed');
        };
    }
});
```

You should also update your view to declare the binding for `username` and `password`

**login.html**

```
<div ng-controller="loginController" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 center-block" id="lgBlock">

    <!-- Login Box Start -->

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-group" name="lgForm">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrName" ng-model="username" required />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" ng-model="password" required />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Login Box End -->

    <!--  error Modal start -->

    <div class="modal" role="modal" id="errorPopup">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Error</div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  error Modal End -->

</div>
```

The way you pass data to the `$scope` is totally up to you and your needs. My suggestion is to determine what you need and only bind that to the `$scope` for example if you only need `data.resultSet` then you should do `$scope.resultSet`. On the other hand, if you need complete access to the `data` object then you should bind `data` to the `$scope` and the you can still access the `resultSet` from there i.e., `$scope.data.resultSet`

**Suggestions:**

Only bind the things you need to reference in the view to the `$scope` for example you don't need access to the `loginSuccess` nor `loginFailure` in the view and you are only using those two functions once, so I recommend you update your `loginController` as follows:

```
app.controller('loginController', function($scope) {

    $scope.login = function() {

        // TODO: if block to validate user input i.e., username and password

        $scope.loginProcedure = {
            adapter: 'SQL',
            procedure: 'login',
            parameters: [$scope.username, $scope.password]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure($scope.loginProcedure, {
            onSuccess: function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                // resultSet is part of data so you don't need to refrences
                // you can use $scope.data.resultSet to access resultSet
                console.log('success: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.data + " : " + $scope.data.resultSet));
            },
            onFailure: function() {
                console.log('failed');
            }
        });
    }
});
```